# why autodetect option not available for me?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to use autowire="autodetect"..

In eclipse code suggest does not show me autodetect as the option..But it shows other values like byname,bytype,constructor..

whats missing in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not offering you `autodetect` because (according to [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)), `autodetect` isn't an option. The valid options are `byName`, `byType` amd `constructor`.

Incidentally, this kind of autowiring is seriously old-fashioned. The annotations `@Autowired` and `@Inject` offer much better control over autowiring  - [see docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).

**update:** The `autodetect` option was deprecated as of Spring 3.x, and so it no longer appears in the documentation. It should still work, however (see the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#AUTOWIRE_AUTODETECT)), so I was wrong to originally say that it wasn't an option.

Comment: Yes u r right..i checked it and there is no option given...
Actually i am going through the Spring in Action third edition book and in that the author explains about this option...

And also on this site http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-in-xml/

he discussed about this option..

was it available in 2.5?

Comment: Thanks alot for looking into my question and clearing my doubt..i think i need to learn looking into the issue deaper..

Comment: @javanerd: `@Autowired` rocks.

Answer (score 0):

The autodetect option is deprecated.

In the newer versions of Spring Framework 4.1.6 I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 83; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'autodetect' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
```

which basically means that now autowire can have only four possible values i.e. [default, no, byName, byType, constructor]